# How to performing calculation between two fields in Django models in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have two models on a many to many relationships and I am trying to subtract one field on a model from the other field on another model. I am having trouble figuring out how to get that done. I am trying to subtract Leave_current_balance from the LeaveBalance model from Total_working_days on the NewLeave model.

I have added the function that handles the leave approval for the Director. There are two authorizers. The first authorizer is the Manager and the second authorizer is the Director. when the leave is authorized by the manager, it is then forwarded to the Director for his approval. I want to adjust the Leave_current_balance once it has been approved by the director. So far both approval is working but I want to be able to adjust the Leave_current_balance once the leave has been approved by the director.

```
class LeaveBalance(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    Leave_current_balance= models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Year=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
             return  self.Year


class NewLeave(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User,default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   leave_balance=models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
    Leave_type=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,default='')
    Total_working_days=models.FloatField(null=True,  blank=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.Leave_type




@login_required()
def unitDirectorForm(request,id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        getstaffid=NewLeave.objects.get(id=id)
        form=DirectorForm(request.POST,instance=getstaffid)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponse('You have successfully approved the leave')

    else:
        getstaffid=NewLeave.objects.get(id=id)
        form=DirectorForm(instance=getstaffid)
    return render(request,'managerauthorisedform.html',{'form':form})






@receiver(post_save, sender=NewLeave)
def update_leave_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if NewLeave.objects.filter(Director_Authorization_Status='Approved'):
        leave_balance_object = Leave_Balance.objects.get(user=instance.user_id)
        leave_balance_object = F('Leave_current_balance') - instance.Total_working_days
        leave_balance_object.save()
```

In the signal, i have checked for director approval before performing the calculation. However the code is generating an error message: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong , whenever a user have a `newLeave` entry you want to adjust your `LeaveBalance` model's `Leave_current_balance` from `newLeave`'s `Total_working_days`. In my opinion actually there is no need to have `leave_balance` in `newLeave` model. You can simple adjust those from `newLeave` model singal ( please go through these links if you don't know about django-signal [link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) [link2](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) ).

And from `newLeave` models post_save signal we can adjust particular user's 
`Leave_current_balance` as follow.

```
from django.db.models import F
from .models import NewLeave, LeaveBalance
@receiver(post_save, sender=NewLeave)
def update_leave_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    leave_balance_object = LeaveBalance.objects.get(user=instance.user_id)
    leave_balance_object = F('Leave_current_balance') - instance.Total_working_days
    leave_balance_object.save()
```

Comment: @Shukil, Thanks heaps that is exactly what I am trying to do, but instead I want to adjust the leave_current_balance as soon as the leave has been approved. I will read through the two links that you have provided.

Comment: Would it be possible to have sender coming from a function in views.py? I have a function in views.py that the leave authorizer used to authorize the leave and I want the signal to be sent as soon as a  leave has been approved.

Comment: i try that, but the i got the error message 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: can you please update your question with your updated code.

Comment: also can you please tell me what are your requirements exactly so that i can able to think about the system in whole.